# Scene.getStylesheets().add() not working inside jar file

Tags: java, jar, resources, javafx-2, maven-3

As long as I run my project directly from Eclipse, I have no problem with that:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());
```

But as soon as I run this code inside of a jar file, the resource is not found (`NullPointerException`).

I tried moving the `css` file to my `src` folder and then only `stylesheet.css`as path instead of `/stylesheet.css`, but this leads to the same problem: Works fine using Eclipse, but not from the jar.

**Hint**: I am using [Zonskis Maven JavaFX Plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/wiki) for generating the jar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wasted my (your) time writing silly **maven** profiles.

instead of :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());
```

### simply write :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");
```

This is how [Zonski](https://github.com/zonski/hello-javafx-maven-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zenjava/examples/hellojfxmaven/HelloJavaFxAndMavenApp.java) load `css` files.

Of course your `stylesheet.css` file should be in `/src/main/resources`, or somewhere on the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: lol, interesting, will verify this later and then select this answers as the correct one ;-) Thanks for the second reply!

Comment: Note to everyone using css in /src/main/resources: You have to make sure the css file is in the root of the resources file, not the project package (e.g. /src/main/resources/com/myorg/myapp).

Comment: This does not work when running the program from a compiled .jar file ... the path to the file is inside the .jar ... shouldn't the file be pulled out of the jar using .getResourceAsStream somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Move your file to `src/main/resources` and add your `css` file :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());
```

Well, if you want to run it from the jar, then change `stylesheet.css` to `stylesheet.bss` ( **binary css**), package your application :

```
mvn clean compile jfx:build-jar
```

and run your jar.

```
java -jar app.jar
```

---

I have a ugly hack to make this a little usable (I'm using **Netbeans**,amazing **maven** integrity):

I create a `project.properties` file in `src/main/resources` directory,

```
file_css= ${file_css} // by default I use *.css file.
```

And make it filterable, in my `POM` file:

```
...
    <build>     
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>        
            <plugins>           
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version> 1.5 </version>
                    <configuration>          
                                    ....
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
</build>

...
```

And create two `maven` profiles, one for `dev`, and the other for `production` (packaging to jar):

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <file_css>stylesheet.bss</file_css>
            </properties>
        </profile>      
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <file_css>stylesheet.css</file_css>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

**So**, you load your  `css` file like this :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ResourceBundle.getBundle("project").getString("file_css")).toExternalForm());
```

I use `production` profile for  packaging, and `dev` for usual actions like `compile, test, run`.

---

**Edit:**
a complete example is hosted on [github](https://github.com/tarrsalah/minimal-javafx-pom).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still the same problem ): Works fine when run from Eclipse, but not from the JAR.

Comment: Thank you, that works when run from the JAR! But is there an intelligent way to automatically use bss when building a JAR file and use css otherwise? Because with bss it won't work when run from Eclipse \:

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf if my solution seems to ugly, try to open an [issue](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin/issues?state=open).

Comment: no, it feels to be an easy to implement way, just need some time to test it ;-) but accepting your answer now, as you answered the original question anyway :-) Thank you very much again!

Comment: tarrsalah, can you have a look at your answer and you POM at home if something for filtering is missing? Which command line command exactly are you using? I never get my variable replace to stylesheet.bss ):

Comment: Answer updated , I will try to update it later with a complete example hosted on github.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Answer updated with a link to the [github](https://github.com/tarrsalah/minimal-javafx-pom) repository link.