Reference a java constant as a Maven property for resource filtering
If I have a java constant somewhere in src/main/java in my maven project, is there some way to reference that constant as a maven property for maven resource filtering?
For example, if I have a class with the following public constant
package my.package;

public class MyClass {
    public static final String MY_PROPERTY = "my.property.name";

}

Is there some way to reference it so that the constant value is used for maven resource filtering.  Something like this if I have a resource in src/main/resources
<myXmlFile>
    <property>
        <name>${java:my.package.MyClass#MY_PROPERTY}</name>
        <value>my value</value>
    </property>
<myXmlFile>


If you need to have it as a compile-time constant - maven templating plugin comes close (but you need to use special placeholders, not property name). Otherwise, use properties file and filer it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287682/override-java-constant-using-maven

Maven does not look inside your code.
